# Using Sum query through a Content Provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite

What I'm trying to do is use a `SUM` query through my content provider. So far I've not been able to do so.

My content provider has a column called credit score. What I'm trying to do is pull the data and add it together to produce a final score for a specific person, i.e. every row with john smith as the name, add the amount listed in the credit score column.

I've found a few solutions but nothing seems to work. I've read on stackoverflow that it cannot be done without a raw query that cannot be performed through a content resolver.

This was the code that was used:

```
    ContentProviderClient client =  getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(AUTHORITY);
    SQLiteDatabase dbHandle= ((BorrowMeContentProvider)client.getLocalContentProvider()).getDbHandle();
    Cursor cursor = dbHandle.rawQuery("SELECT sum("+BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_CREDIT_SCORE+") FROM "+BorrowMeTable.DATABASE_TABLE +" WHERE "+BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME+"= \""+ nameOfThePersonString+"\"", null);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     int cnt =  cursor.getInt(0);
     cursor.close();
     cursor.deactivate();
     client.release();
```

I get an error when using this, which I think has to do with the `getDbHandle()` - this method had to be created in my content provider (as it didn't exist) but it returns null.

This is the error I get:

```
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fthatnoise.borrow.me/com.fthatnoise.borrow.me.PersonRecord}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at com.fthatnoise.borrow.me.PersonRecord.fillData(PersonRecord.java:90)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at com.fthatnoise.borrow.me.PersonRecord.onCreate(PersonRecord.java:52)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5048)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-29 16:16:24.369: E/AndroidRuntime(28802):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2052)
```

Am I on the right track here or way off base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add AS creditcardtotal before FROM in your query

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying, I tried adding it and it still gave me the error message.

Comment: what is line 90? in the logcat double click on the line at com.fthatnoise.borrow.me.PersonRecord.fillData(PersonRecord.java:90)

Comment: Cursor cursor = dbHandle.rawQuery("SELECT sum("+BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_CREDIT_SCORE+") AS creditcardtotal FROM "+BorrowMeTable.DATABASE_TABLE +" WHERE "+BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME+"= \""+ nameOfThePersonString+"\"", null);

Comment: I think I understand - the line above 90 is - SQLiteDatabase dbHandle= ((BorrowMeContentProvider)client.getLocalContentProvider()).getDbHandle(); - The problem being I returned null in my content provider for that method as I stated because I'm not sure what to put there

Comment: Yes, that was it - I had to return a writable database. thank you for your help!